# hello i have a little problem whit my function I would like that the balls do not exceed the width of the html

Tags: javascript, html, css

the function is executed very well, the problem is that when the balls appear randomly, at times they are too close to the edge to see outside, suddenly they shift the HTML and its created white borders, in responsive it is a horror.
if you can help me think of a method to delimit the html so that the balls follow the html border and never go beyond it.
thank you in advance

```js
let time = 000;
const creation_de_cercle = () =>{
    const r = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = ()=> Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = ()=> Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

    const colorString = ()=> `rgb(${r()}, ${g()}, ${b()})`;
    // permet de créé une couleur random en compilent les trois variable au dessus 
    // const colorString = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  
    const circle = document.createElement("span");// creation d'element html rapide avec "document.body.appendChild(circle);"
    circle.classList.add('cercle');// ahoute un class 'cercle' a la span
    //permet de créé un taille aleatoir de min"30" 
    let taille_du_cercle = Math.random() * 150 + 30 + "px"; 
    // injection du top et du lef en random 
    circle.style.top = Math.random() * 100 + "%"; 
    circle.style.left = Math.random() * 100 + "%";
    console.log(circle.style.left);
    // inject une hauteur a la balise "span"
    circle.style.height = taille_du_cercle;
    circle.style.width = taille_du_cercle;
    // random la rotation des boules à chaque apparition 
    circle.style.transform ="rotate("+ Math.random()*360 +"deg"+")";
     // random la linea-gradient des boules à chaque apparition 
    circle.style.background = "linear-gradient("+ Math.random()*360 +"deg,"+ colorString() + "0%,"+ colorString()+"100%)";
    circle.style.zIndex = Math.random()* 1000 ;
    // circle.style.boxShadow = Math.random()
    document.body.appendChild(circle); 
    // efface les boulles 
    setTimeout(() => {
        circle.remove();
    },12000);
    time=+4000;
    

};
```

```css
body{
    height:200vh;

}
/* edition de la class créé en JS  */
.cercle{ 
    position: absolute; 
    border-radius:500px; 
    animation:animation 100s;
    transition: .5s;
    box-shadow: 2px 35px 85px -8px rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.582);
    
}

/* creation de l'animation pour HUE_ROTATE */
@keyframes animation {
    0%{
       
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:0;
        
    }
    10%{
        opacity:1;
    }
    50%{
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        top: -100%;
        transform:rotate(1200deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```